# print values of input element after form redirection in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am very much new to cakephp. I have created a simple form with input controls on it as follows:

```
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('address', array('rows' => '3'));
    echo $this->Form->input('aaa', array(
        'type'      => 'date',
        'label'     => 'select',
        'before'    => '--before--',
        'after'     => '--after--',
        'between'   => 'Date',
        'separator' => '****',
        'empty'     => '--select--'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->checkbox('subjects', array('value' => 'Java'));
?>
java
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('gen', array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'options' => array('m', 'f')
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('listbox', array('options' => array(1,2,3,4,5), 'multiple' => 'multiple'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

i wish to print the values entered in these components on another page. how do i do that?
i tried to do it with the help of session(which seems to be inappropriate) as follows:

```
public function contactus() {
        if ($this->request->data!=null) {
            $var=$this->request->data;
            $this -> Session -> write('myvar', $this->request->data);
            //$this->set($var, $this->request->data);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contactview'));
        }
    }
```

but it outputs array and i cant use session to store each component's value.
how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the session, I used `this->data` and it was able to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to cakephp book (Form: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1384/Creating-Forms)

```
   <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(null, 
  array('url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add'))); 
    ?>

     //Output:
    <form method="post" action="/recipes/add">
```

Therefore , just change your `create` function and add the `url` option.